# How to write a long data type as a index of a list in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list which has a very large index but kotlin says I can't put long value as `index(count[index/2)`. Any help?

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var maxi:Int = 1000000

    var value:Int = 0
    var sum:Long = 0
    var number:Int = 0
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var total:Int = reader.nextInt()
    var a = mutableListOf(1)
    a.removeAt(0)
    var count: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(maxi, value))
    count.add(0)
    var i:Int = 0
    while(i<total){
        number= reader.nextInt()
        a.add(i,number)
        count[a[i]] ++
        sum += a[i]
        i ++
    }
    var ans = mutableListOf(0)
    ans.removeAt(0)
    i = 0
    while(i<total){
        sum -= a[i]
        count[a[i]] --
        if (sum % 2.toLong() == 0.toLong() && sum/2.toLong() <= maxi.toLong() && count[sum/2] >0){
            ans.add(i+1)
        }
        sum += a[i]
        count[a[i]]++
        i ++
    }
    println(ans.size)
    for(item in ans){
        print(item)
        print(" ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays/lists in Java/Kotlin can't be indexed by long values, because it doesn't make too much sense to have such HUGE collections. Max value of int is ~2.14mld, so even using ints as indexes, the biggest possible array of ints takes at least ~8GB of RAM. List probably takes much more (?).

Why do you need such huge collections in the first place? Do you maybe need a map instead of an array/list? (Sorry, I'm not sure what your code does)

Comment: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1077/C
I am actually trying to solve this problem in kotlin and mapping is not a good way to approach in my opinion. that's why I used the above approach where the secondary array will count the frequency of each element. I am kinda new In kotlin shifted from c++ so many things are still new for me here..Thanks for the clarification that i cant use long in kotlin index

Comment: If you need to calculate frequency then this is the perfect example where we need to use maps. This is not really specific to Kotlin, you would have the same problem in C++. You can't create an array that contains frequency of every possible long value, because such array would be millions/milliards times bigger than you RAM. And then iterating through this array to find existing elements would take forever. Of course, if values are from some range e.g. 0-1000 then it makes sense to use array instead of map. But then we don't need to use long as an index.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I read the problem carefully and now I understand why you wanted to have such big indexes. Sum of numbers can be potentially as big as 2e11, so you can't keep it as int. But didn't you notice that you created your list with size of 1e6 and then you would like to access its elements much, much bigger than that? How is it even possible? The problem is that you didn't notice that sum can't be really such big in practice. I may be wrong, but I believe if it exceeds 3e6 then the problem does not have solutions, because there can't be a single element that can equal all other elements.

Comment: Summing up: you should check if the sum is bigger than 1e6 and in that case assume that such element does not exists. If it is lower than 1e6 then you can safely cast it to int to use as an index.

Comment: Or you can keep `sum` as int instead of long and add checks for exceeding 3e6 - then return immediately with no solutions.